# Force java xjc compiler to generate unbounded generics

Tags: java, generics, jaxb, wildcard, xjc

I have following XSD schema:

```xml
<xs:schema>
    <xs:complexType name="Person">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="LastName"/>
            <xs:element name="FirstName"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="ListOfPersons">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Persons" type="Person"></xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:element name="List" type="ListOfPersons"/>
</xs:schema>
```

When i generate java classes with XJC compiler i receive (among others) following class:

```
public class ListOfPersons {

    @XmlElement(name = "Persons")
    protected List<Person> persons;

    public List<Person> getPersons() {
        if (persons == null) {
            persons = new ArrayList<Person>();
        }
        return this.persons;
    }
```

}

My question is. Is there any possibility to generate persons of type `List<? extends Person>` instead of plain `List<Person>`?

Comment: Have you looked at this https://github.com/jawi/jaxb-inherit already? I can't say if you can reach the desired result with it. What have you tried already?

Comment: Hi, thanks for comment. Yes I have and i'm using this plugin. It is perfect if you want to extend/implement sth by the generated class but there is no option (at leasy i couldn't find) that solves my problem with generics :(

Comment: If the existing inheritance plugin does not provide that functionality, then you probably have to create your own plugin. But that's just an uneducated guess.